# Numbers on clock represented by polyhedra

Tags: geometry, sequences-and-series, polyhedra

[image: REPRESENT CLOCK BY POLYHEDRON]

The "1" is replaced with a four-sided object, then the next one could be a five sided object, then six (the cube), but then after that, it is either a five-sided pyramid, or a eight-sided die.

Would you please give me an explanation or a rule for this image? Enlighten me, please!

Comment: I don't see a pattern, except that the polyhedra are increasing in complexity. However, I want one of these clocks for my office!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any particular pattern to these shapes other than increasing "complexity" in some sense (as mentioned in the comments), but to describe exactly which polyhedra are pictured:

| $n$ | Polyhedron | Vertices | Edges | Faces |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | [Tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) | 4 | 6 | 4 |
| $2$ | [Square pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramid) | 5 | 8 | 5 |
| $3$ | [Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) | 8 | 12 | 6 |
| $4$ | [Octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron) | 6 | 12 | 8 |
| $5$ | [Pentagonal trapezohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_trapezohedron) | 12 | 20 | 10 |
| $6$ | [Cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron) | 12 | 24 | 14 |
| $7$ | [Dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron) | 20 | 30 | 12 |
| $8$ | [Icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) | 12 | 30 | 20 |
| $9$ | [Icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron) | 30 | 60 | 32 |
| $10$ | [Snub cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_cube) | 24 | 60 | 38 |
| $11$ | [Rhombicosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicosidodecahedron) | 60 | 120 | 62 |
| $12$ | [Small stellated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_stellated_dodecahedron) | 12 | 30 | 12 |

If one considers the small stellated dodecahedron as a simple polyhedron rather than a self-intersecting [Kepler-Poinsot polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%E2%80%93Poinsot_polyhedron), it has $32$ vertices, $90$ edges, and $60$ faces.